# Set auto increment variable in php for voucher codes

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to set a variable that will auto increase always by 1 in form submit and if exist to do +1 if already ia in db.

For example :

if the form is submitted almost the same time by two different users .i have tried with primary key Id but some times it gets increased by two.

My code for inserting is

```
<?php
require('db.php');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');
include("auth.php"); //include auth.php file on all secure pages
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$status = "";

$signintime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$customid =$_REQUEST['customid'];
$seat =$_REQUEST['seat'];
$matchtype= $_REQUEST['matchtype'];
$ticketprice=$_REQUEST['ticketprice'];
$barcode= $_REQUEST['barcode'];
$expdate= $_REQUEST['expdate'];
$expdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()+36000);
$submittedby = $_SESSION["username"];

$ins_query="insert into kozani(`customid`,`signintime`,`seat`,`matchtype`,`ticketprice`,`barcode`,`expdate`,`submittedby`)values('$customid','$signintime','$seat','$matchtype','$ticketprice','$barcode','$expdate','$submittedby')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `customid` = '$customid',`signintime`='$signintime',`seat`='$seat',`matchtype`='$matchtype',`ticketprice`='$ticketprice',`expdate`='$expdate',`barcode`= IFNULL (`barcode`,'$barcode')";
```

Where customid is the value of vouvher

Thank you.

Comment: Have you try any code so far? If yes then add over here...

Comment: I have tried with Ajax on submit button hover to echo last value of variable +1 but I don't know if it is good idea I will post the code later

Answer (score 0):

you can use update , you need to adapt this code (php)

```
if( question )
    UPDATE `table` SET `parameter` = `parameter` +1  WHERE `parameter` =".$value.";
else
    UPDATE `table` SET `parameter` = `parameter` +2  WHERE `parameter` =".$value.";
```

Comment: could you please provide the code to fit my edited question ?